# Where can I find the HTML5 specs, and details of which browsers support which features?

Tags: html, browser

I was wondering where can I find the HTML5 specs for Internet Explorer, Opera, Firefox and Google Chrome browsers?

Comment: Do you want the spec (there is only one spec), or a list of features that each browser supports?

Answer (score 3):

Fresh off the presses (6 days ago as of the time of this post):

Editor's Draft 25 January 2011
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html

But below is a very good resource about new features in HTML5, including what is currently supported by various browsers.  However, even better than a static mapping of what's currently supported, the book includes a chapter how to detect whether a given feature is supported, so your HTML5 can work on future browsers as more HTML5 features become more widely supported:

[Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/)
[Chapter 2 - Detecting HTML5 Features](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/detect.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good site: http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/4-useful-HTML5-browser-support-overviews.html). :)

Comment: http://caniuse.com/ seems to be the most useful of the sites that links to. Got to remember that myself. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) for feature detection in your clients browsers, then do what you can to patch up the user experience.

Alternatively, if all you're looking for is comparisons of different browsers, you can view their homepage in your browser of choice to see what it supports.